# Null Reference Exception for dynamic ascx User Control

Tags: c#, webforms, nullreferenceexception, dynamic-controls

I'm working on a user form in which I'd like to dynamically generate as many secondary phone fields as the user wants (on button click event). I've followed Daniel's dynamic control instantiation on this page: [How can I re-instantiate dynamic ASP.NET user controls without using a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324003/)

I've also implemented the "Event Bubbling" solution proposed by lordscarlet on this page: [Eventhandling in ascx usercontrols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92860/)

**The relevant portion of my user.aspx page:**

```
<asp:Panel ID="phonePnl" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
            <tr><td><asp:Button ID="phoneBtn" Text="Add Secondary Phone" OnClick="phoneBtn_Click" runat="server" /></td></tr>
```

**Relevant portion of user.aspx.cs CodeBehind**

```
    // ============================================================================
protected void phoneBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl controlToAdd = new UserControl();
    controlToAdd = (UserControl)controlToAdd.LoadControl("~/DynamicData/FieldTemplates/SecondaryPhone.ascx");

    controlToAdd.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    Panel phonePnl = (Panel)fvUser.FindControl("phonePnl");

    Literal lit = new Literal();
    lit.Text = "<tr><td>Secondary Phone</td><td>";
    phonePnl.Controls.Add(lit);
    phonePnl.Controls.Add(controlToAdd);
    lit = new Literal();
    lit.Text = "</td></tr>";
    phonePnl.Controls.Add(lit);

    myControlList.Add(controlToAdd.ID, controlToAdd.AppRelativeVirtualPath);
    Session["myControlList"] = myControlList;
}

// ============================================================================
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        myControlList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Session["myControlList"] = myControlList;
    }
    else
    {
        myControlList = (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["myControlList"];

        foreach (var registeredControlId in myControlList.Keys)
        {
            UserControl controlToAdd = new UserControl();
            controlToAdd = (UserControl)controlToAdd.LoadControl(myControlList[registeredControlId]);
            Panel phonePnl = new Panel();
            phonePnl = (Panel)fvUser.FindControl("phonePnl");
            phonePnl.Controls.Add(controlToAdd);
        }
    }
    base.OnInit(e);
}

// ============================================================================
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
    SecondaryPhoneControl.BubbleClick += new EventHandler(admin_user_BubbleClick);
}

// ============================================================================
private void admin_user_BubbleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //todo
}
```

Note that I've added the last line:
    Session["myControlList"] = myControlList;

Also, fvUser is just my FormView ID in the user.aspx page.

Although it wasn't in Daniel's solution, my thinking was that for each control you add, you need to add it to your Dictionary. Am I completely misguided in this?

My user control is an ascx with a TextBox and a Button(for deletion of the control, if the user decides they don't want that field). Note that this deletion isn't really implemented yet, but the Event is there in my parent codebehind for after this issue is resolved.

**SecondaryPhone.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" CodeBehind="SecondaryPhone.ascx.cs" Inherits="TwentyFourSeven.DynamicData.FieldTemplates.SecondaryPhone" %>
```

**SecondaryPhone.ascx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web.DynamicData;

namespace TwentyFourSeven.DynamicData.FieldTemplates

{
public partial class SecondaryPhone : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void SetPhone(String phone)
    {
        secPhoneTxt.Text = phone;
    }

    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        base.LoadViewState(savedState);
        secPhoneTxt.Text = (String)ViewState["secPhoneTxt"];
    }

    protected override object SaveViewState()
    {
        ViewState["secPhoneTxt"] = secPhoneTxt.Text;
        return base.SaveViewState();
    }

    private void secPhoneBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public event EventHandler BubbleClick;

    protected void OnBubbleClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BubbleClick != null)
        {
            BubbleClick(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.secPhoneBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.secPhoneBtn_Click);
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
    }
}
}
```

When debugging, OnInit works correctly when the page is first loaded, and clicking the Add Secondary Phone button works on the first click. The second click throws a Null Reference Exception (Object reference not set to an instance of an object) on this line of my OnInit method:

```
phonePnl.Controls.Add(controlToAdd);
```

In debugging I noticed that on the first click of the button, in my phoneBtn_Click method, the controlToAdd.Application, controlToAdd.Cache, etc. also throw Null Reference Exceptions, but it still generates the control and returns the page. It also adds the control and its ID to the Dictionary.

Then on the second click of the button, right before it hits the line that causes the exception, my phonePnl variable is null. I can surmise this is what's causing the exception, but why would my phonePnl variable be null in this case, and not in the second OnInit call/first postback?

I have been banging my head against this all day, and I'm hoping someone can offer some insight.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `controlToAdd.LoadControl` use `Page.LoadControl` and see if that works

Comment: The same exception occurs - is there a difference between referencing the Page LoadControl as opposed to the specific control's LoadControl?