# Handle selectedchange event in user control from aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a filterControl on Main.aspx page , and this filterControl has another control called filterList.

I want to handle for listbox in filterlist control from main.aspx.

how can do it ?

[image]

need your helps.

Comment: Handle the ListBox' selectedindexchanged event, raise a custom event declared in your usercontrol, handle that event in your page. If the UserControls are nested more, you need to bubble that event up to the page in the same way. So your "deepest" control handles  the ListBox event and raises a custom event, it's parent UserControl catches that event and raises another custom event itself and so on.

Comment: I tried a lot of samples for this but i cant fire it.This solition is work for me ? Can u see it ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92860/eventhandling-in-ascx-usercontrols

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

### User control code behind

```
public event Action<string> MyHandler = delegate { };

protected void myListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
   // ....
   this.MyHandler(this.myListBox.SelectedValue);
}
```

### ASPX

```
<uc1:YourControl OnMyHandler="myPageHandler" ....
```

### ASPX code behind

```
protected void myPageHandler(string customMessage)
{
   // your awesome stuff goes here
}
```

Comment: It fired myListBox_SelectedIndexChanged but myPageHandler didnt handle it

Comment: Double check you are handling the event on the page `<uc1:YourControl OnMyHandler="myPageHandler" ....` and that in your `SelectedIndexChanged` event you are **actually firing the custom event** `this.MyHandler(this.myListBox.SelectedValue);`